# Could not find function 'spacy-transformers.TransformerModel.v3' in function registry 'architectures'

Tags: named-entity-recognition, bert-language-model, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

I was trying to create a custom NER model. I used spacy library to create the model. And this line of code is to create the config file from the `base.config` file.
**My code is :**

```js
!python -m spacy init fill-config /content/drive/MyDrive/NER_RE_New/NER/base_config.cfg /content/drive/MyDrive/NER_RE_New/NER/config.cfg
```

**Error** :

```html
catalogue.RegistryError: [E893] Could not find function 'spacy-transformers.TransformerModel.v3' in function registry 'architectures'. If you're using a custom function, make sure the code is available. If the function is provided by a third-party package, e.g. spacy-transformers, make sure the package is installed in your environment.
```

**Available names:**

```js
spacy-legacy.CharacterEmbed.v1, 
spacy-legacy.HashEmbedCNN.v1, 
spacy-legacy.MaxoutWindowEncoder.v1, 
spacy-legacy.MishWindowEncoder.v1, 
spacy-legacy.MultiHashEmbed.v1, 
spacy-legacy.TextCatBOW.v1, 
spacy-legacy.TextCatCNN.v1, 
spacy-legacy.TextCatEnsemble.v1, 
spacy-legacy.Tok2Vec.v1, 
spacy-legacy.TransitionBasedParser.v1, 
spacy-transformers.Tok2VecTransformer.v1,
spacy-transformers.TransformerListener.v1, 
spacy-transformers.TransformerModel.v1, 
spacy.CharacterEmbed.v1, 
spacy.EntityLinker.v1, 
spacy.HashEmbedCNN.v1, 
spacy.MaxoutWindowEncoder.v2, 
spacy.MishWindowEncoder.v2, 
spacy.MultiHashEmbed.v1, 
spacy.PretrainCharacters.v1, 
spacy.PretrainVectors.v1, 
spacy.Tagger.v1, 
spacy.TextCatBOW.v1, 
spacy.TextCatCNN.v1, 
spacy.TextCatEnsemble.v2, 
spacy.TextCatLowData.v1, 
spacy.Tok2Vec.v2, 
spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1, 
spacy.TorchBiLSTMEncoder.v1, 
spacy.TransitionBasedParser.v1, 
spacy.TransitionBasedParser.v2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened since spacy had a new update 3.1 recently. And the base_config file have the architecture mentioned as "spacy-transformers.TransformerModel.v3". Change it into "spacy-transformers.TransformerModel.v1"

```
[components.transformer.model]
@architectures = "spacy-transformers.TransformerModel.v1"
name = "roberta-base"
tokenizer_config = {"use_fast": true}
```

Comment: Glad you got it working, but you shouldn't have to lower the version. It sounds like maybe you need to upgrade `spacy-transformers`.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I was having the same problem. I just figured out that the problem is caused when you install spacy-transformers library this way: `pip install spacy[transformers]`.

The solution:

Install it directly from their GitHub repo like this:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/explosion/spacy-transformers
```

Answer (score 1):

resolve this error by:, execute the below lines on cmd, jupyter anywhere:

1. install the latest spacy: `pip install spacy`
2. install latest en core web sm: `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

Answer (score 0):

When I updated the version from 3.4.7, the issue was resolved.